# Cleaning up a certain level of a json file converted to a series

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas

I have a certain level of a json file which I've transformed into a series within a DF. This level has different types of messages though and I'm looking for a way to clean up this series the best way possible. Below, you can see one of the messages I have in the series.

```
["Strategy B P-Q D-", {"type": "phone", "text": "21-01-30-20-12"}," (USDT_ANKR): deal_283850: Deal completed. Profit:  +13.", {"type": "phone", "text": "97856991"}," USDT (13.98 $) (3.14% from total volume (2.5% before trailing)) . ", {"type": "hashtag", "text": "#profit"}, " about 5 hours"]
```

This LIST is of course a representation of this json structure:

```
   [
    "Strategy B P-Q D-",
    {
     "type": "phone",
     "text": "21-01-30-20-12"
    },
    " (USDT_ANKR): deal_283850: Deal completed. Profit:  +13.",
    {
     "type": "phone",
     "text": "97856991"
    },
    " USDT (13.98 $) (3.14% from total volume (2.5% before trailing)) . ",
    {
     "type": "hashtag",
     "text": "#profit"
    },
    " about 5 hours"
   ]
```

And the clean message is simply:

```
"Strategy B P-Q D-21-01-30-20-12 (USDT_ANKR): deal_283853127: Deal completed. Profit: +13.97856991 USDT (13.98 $) (3.14% from total volume (2.5% before trailing))  #profit about 5 hours"
```

On the other hand, not all messages arrive that noisy. The following is also one of the messages from the same json file. It's quite cleaner by default.

```
"GridBot (USDT_THETA): bot_346214: Grid line 4.556439 (4.556439) profit at the price of 2.18927"
```

Currently, I'm dumping these json messages (transforming them into strings) and removing the noise (which I've manually added to a list, like so:

```
noise = ['"]', '"}, "', ' {"', ' "', '", {"type": "phone", "text":']
df = df["messages"].str.replace('|'.join(noise), '', regex=True)
```

Is there a cleaner way of doing the same - i.e. cleaning up the noisy content to get the clean messages only - without having to manually create a list with all noise-patterns and remove them from the strings?

I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all of your "noise" dictionaries have the text in them, rather than trying to pull out the text you don't want, you could pull out the text you do want:

```python
value = [
    "Strategy B P-Q D-",
    {
        "type": "phone",
        "text": "21-01-30-20-12"
    },
    " (USDT_ANKR): deal_283850: Deal completed. Profit:  +13.",
    {
        "type": "phone",
        "text": "97856991"
    },
    " USDT (13.98 $) (3.14% from total volume (2.5% before trailing)) . ",
    {
        "type": "hashtag",
        "text": "#profit"
    },
    " about 5 hours"
]

value = "".join([x if isinstance(x, str) else x["text"] for x in value])
print(value)
```

Which will output:

```
Strategy B P-Q D-21-01-30-20-12 (USDT_ANKR): deal_283850: Deal completed. Profit:  +13.97856991 USDT (13.98 $) (3.14% from total volume (2.5% before trailing)) . #profit about 5 hours
```

Comment: Thanks! I see this is the way to go, but how would you apply this to the entire dataframe column/feature? I've tried a few different things, but always end up with a `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

Comment: Nevermind, I've figured it out. `df["messages"] = df["messages"].apply(lambda row: "".join([x if isinstance(x, str) else x["text"] for x in row]))`. Again: thanks!